# Is there a software/website to play notes on snare drums?

Tags: software, sight-reading, snare-drum

I am a student for (or is it 'to'? I'll have to look that up on ell.stackexchange) snare drums, and I'm given sight-reading homework, with lots of triplets with rests, sixteenth note triplets and all kinds of subdivisions.

Is there a software or a website that you can edit and play notes on (including most subdivisions, sixteenth note triplets are helpful, but not nessecary)?

For example, you could put in a triplet with a rest on the first triplet, then an eighth note and then a rest, and then the software/website reads it and plays it to a tempo you set it.

Comment: something like this? switch from "voice" to "drums" http://www.philtulga.com/counter.html

Comment: It's ok, but you have to buy it to use triplets

Comment: I can really recommend Guitar Pro 6 if you're still interested. It is an awesome program with a great sound engine which sounds very realistic. It's also easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, plenty.

Guitar Pro is commercial, but there are free alternatives:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/

I'm sure Tux has the MIDI voice for percussion available.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you will find many programs that give you want you are looking for (any notation program for example).  **However**, you need to learn to *play* the rhythms yourself.  Using the programs will result in you learning by *rote*, which is essentially just copying what you're hearing without really understanding the concepts.  This is akin to being a parrot.

Being a musical parrot is not sustainable nor is it as fun as being a musical person.

Either ask your teacher to give you materials that are less complicated, or take the time to learn the concepts necessary in order to play the appropriate rhythms.

Comment: I know how to play it, I'm just making sure that I'm correct. Thanks for the advice anyways.